# Configure collection name depending on attribute field value

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a collection named **"Google_Analytics_Extraction"** that persist a spring pojo class that contain a attribute named viewID. I need to store in differentes collections for each viewID by adding the viewID to the end of the basic name **"Google_Analytics_Extraction"** to be like **"Google_Analytics_Extraction_xxxx"**.

I know that we can perform it by mongoTemplate by I need to do it dynamically with @Document annotation maybe with **SPeL** language or something else.

This is my class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document("Google_Analytics_Extraction_")
public class GAnalyticsDataEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String viewID;
    private String dateExtraction;
    private String fromToDate;
    private Document dimensionDocument;
    private Document metricDocument;
```

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved with Spel language

```
@org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document("Google_Analytics_Extraction__#{@mongoConfig.getDefaultViewID()}")
public class GAnalyticsDataEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String viewID;
    private String dateExtraction;
    private String fromToDate;
    private Document dimensionDocument;
    private Document metricDocument;
```

I add a bean MongoConfig with a getter to a default view ID

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
public class MongoConfig {

    private String defaultViewID;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initViewt() {
        defaultViewID = "36293746";
    }
}
```

this viewId is changed by a setter before the call of the save method like this

```
 mongoConfig.setDefaultViewID(viewID);
        gAnalyticsEntityRepository.saveAll(gaKeywordReportingList);
```

Thank you